# lombok Log4j in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, lombok

I work for a legacy spring boot project and they used @Log4j from lombok to display logs, but it seems that logging is disabled somewhere because no log is displayed.

Where I can verify if there is some configuration to disable logging.

This is an example for logging:

```
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j;
//........
@Log4j
public abstract class MyClassImpl implements MyClass{
    public String extractPNS(final String session, final String nomFichier, final String path, final String encoding) {
        MyClassImpl.log.debug("My class execution start...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be log folder inside your application . First check the config in any .properties file inside your application name

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked log level? If it is set to `INFO` you won't be able to see `DEBUG` logs. It is configurable under `*.properties` or `*.yml` in `src/main/resources`. Also check for `log4j.xml` file which might be used co to configure `Log4j`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old but I think it still needs an answer.

It is better to logging facade `Slf4j` instead of implementation specific `log4j` like this:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public abstract class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {
    public String extractPNS(final String session, final String nomFichier, 
       final String path, final String encoding) {
        log.info("My class execution start...");
    }
}
```

Then make sure you have a valid `log4j` config available in Spring Boot App's classpath somewhere that doesn't disable logging at `info` level.